# XML RPC API error code :2945 message INVALID_TICKET

Tags: php, curl, zoho

I am trying to insert data in to my zoho creator application form using php curl request.
when i executed the code i'm getting error

Here is the code snippet that i have used:

```
$xml = "
    <ZohoCreator>
        <applicationlist>
            <application name='APPLICATION_NAME'>
                <formlist>
                    <form name='FORM_NAME'>
                        <add>
                            <field name='Order_id'>
                                <value>1</value>
                            </field>
                            <field name='first_name'>
                                <value>first_name</value>
                            </field>
                            <field name='last_name'>
                                <value>last_name</value>
                            </field>
                        </add>
                    </form>
                </formlist>
            </application>
        </applicationlist>
    </ZohoCreator>
    ";

insert_record($xml);

function insert_record($xml_string){

    $api_url = "https://creator.zoho.com/api/xml/write";
    $post_params = array();
    $post_params['authtoken'] = "*********";
    $post_params['zc_ownername'] = "*********";

    $post_params['scope'] = 'creatorapi';
    $post_params ['XMLString'] = $xml_string;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

when i executed this code, got response as below :

```
{"code":2945,"message":"INVALID_TICKET"}
```

why i'm getting this error response, how to make it work